# How to pass a custom generator to OpenApi CodeGen CLI

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm trying to mount a custom generator for OpenApi Generator CLI but I'm getting

> [error] Check the spelling of the generator's name and try again.

This is my current setup:

```
def openApiGeneratorConfig = {
    classpath configurations.openApiGenerator
    mainClass = 'org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator'
}

task generateApi(type: JavaExec) {
    configure openApiGeneratorConfig
    systemProperties = ['apis': '', 'models': '']
    args 'generate'
    args '-g', 'dev.rifaii.CustomGenerator'
    args '-i', 'http://localhost:9903/v3/api-docs.yaml'
    args '-o', "$projectDir"
    args '-t', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/templates/"
    args '-c', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/config.json"
    args '--skip-validate-spec'
}
```

Comment: Is your generator developed within the OpenAPI generator project or is it a standalone project/folder?

Comment: Just a standalone file that extends JavaClientCodegen, I managed to get it working by putting the file in another module. Will post a detailed answer later